# How to hide facebook logout button

Tags: facebook

I have a strange problem.  I don t if it is a problem :)
Well I am tring to login my web site with facebook login.
I am making this facebook user to my web site user and I am giving session to that user.
The problem is I am trying to hide facebook log out button. Because it is useless and confusing the mind. User should click the signout button to logout.

the questing is how can i hide facebook logout button after that user login with facebook account.

Answer (score 1):

just change autologoutlink value:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="false" onlogin="window.location.reload();"></fb:login-button>
```